# Visual Studio Installer project throws no errors on build but msi/exe files are not created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have an old solution that used to work and had many versions and multiple installer projects,
at some point one of the installer projects stopped creating msi/exe files.

small changes have been made to ProjectInstaller class and the project itself.

upon rebuilding the installer project the according to the log there are 0 errors, build is successful
but no files are created.

Comment: Check you bin folder for HOST files.  Delete.  These files are locks so when on a network drive two people do not try to compile at same time.

Comment: @jdweng do you mean project/bin folder? I have deleted it, it is created again along with debug and release, but they are all empty, checked out the entire solution for editing, didn't help either.

Comment: Are there any files in the bin folder?  Your results may be in either the Debug or Release folder.

Comment: @jdweng sorry, actually there is no bin folder, the msi and exe used to be generated in the project/debug and project/release folder, when I delete them and compile, they are created again but no files inside

Comment: Are there any files in the obj folder?  The compiler create intermediate files in the obj and then links together to create the exe.  I've seen cases with new projects where OP did not do a saveall and project was created in the user temp area.  It sound like the project is being built in a folder that you do not have write permission, but you are creating the bin/release/debug so it must be something else.

Comment: well, I came across answers when they talk about permissions, so I have opened VS as admin, I try to rebuild other projects in the solution, the exe and obj files there are created properly as well an the msi and exe files in other projects in the same solution. except  that one project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, my own mistake, there WAS an error in the build, it was neglected by the 'Error List' tab of the logger for some reason, which is strange,

now its just a missing file and I can work with that.

Comment: Yes, missing files (red underlined files in View > File System in the project) cause silent failure